# invocar bash mediante [-v]

Tags: bash

Tengo el siguiente script de bash hecho:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo " -- Fichero A--"
echo "1) URL de descarga: ";
echo "https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic";
echo "";
echo "2) Formato y nombre del fichero";

FICHERO="train.csv"
NOMBRE="${FICHERO%.*}"
EXTENSION="${FICHERO##*.}"

echo "NOMBRE: " $NOMBRE
echo "EXTENSION: " $EXTENSION

echo "";
echo "3) Número de filas y columnas";
echo "Número de filas: "; 
cat train.csv | wc -l
echo "Número de columnas: "; 
awk '{print NF}' train.csv | sort -nu | tail -n 1

echo "";
echo "4) Tipo de datos de cada columna";
awk -F, 'NR==1;NR==2{print typeof($1)","typeof($2)","typeof($3)", "typeof($4)","typeof($5)","typeof($6)","typeof($7)","typeof($8)","typeof($9)","typeof($10)","typeof($11)","typeof($12)}' train.csv
```

La invocación la hago mediante `./A.sh` y se ejecuta sin problemas.

Quiero hacerla mediante `./A.sh [-v]` pero actualmente me da error.
ERROR: `bash: ./A.sh[-v]: No existe el archivo o el directorio`
Cómo puedo resolverlo?

La finalidad del script consiste en hacer un resumen de la información del Dataset (indicando el número de filas y columnas, el nombre y extensión del fichero y tipo de valores en cada columna) que estoy leyendo, en este caso es del Titanic [train.csv]

Gracias.

Comment: No estarás quitando un espacio? Es decir, debería ser, `./A.sh "[-v]"`, con el espacio en medio y el parámetro entrecomillado

Comment: @Cuauhtli, me faltaba el espacio, pero sin comillas funciona, gracias!